# Digits recognition with CMU Sphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

Hi Recognition Experts,

I have a lot of mp3-files (original audio stream samplerate was 11.025 kHz) containing digits (0 - 9).

Different speakers (male/female) say for example "One", "Seven", "Three" etc. with pauses between them (~ 2 - 2.5 second)

I'm going to use CMU Sphinx to recognize the speech (desktop application). So I have some questions:

1. **MP3 decoding**: How do I decode my mp3 files meaning what samplerate
   should I specify to ffmpeg (as I know it's not recomended to
   upsample/downsample streams). Should I filter noises and/or frequency bands while decoding?
2. **Acoustic models**: If I *don't* upsample/downsample the stream, how can
   I find an acoustic model supporting 11025 kHz. If I *do*, what is the best model for digits?
3. **Recognition mode**: I found there are two modes for transcribing - Key
   spotting and Recognition. Whichmode would be better taking into
   account I have only digits (and some noise)

Thanks

**UPD:**

Nikolay, thank you for the answer. I've tried what you propose - it works!

If you don't mind I'd like to ask some additional qiestions:

1. I found that one of the voxforge acoustic models is more accurate than en-us-8khz. Is it ok?
2. Only 45% of files are recognized correct. Other 55% has 20-90% mistakes. Thus my question: Is there a possibility to estimate confidence of obtained results? For example, I could skip the files, which are "not surely" recognized?
3. If answer 2 is "no", what can you suggest to improve the accuracy? I know, the question is very abstract...

Thank you in advance!

**UPD2:**

By the way, the best parameters set (I just went through the various parameters) is:

```
-remove_dc yes -remove_noise no -vad_threshold 3.4 -vad_prespeech 19 -vad_postspeech 37 -silprob 2.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MP3 decoding: How do I decode my mp3 files meaning what samplerate should I specify to ffmpeg (as I know it's not recomended to upsample/downsample streams). Should I filter noises and/or frequency bands while decoding?

```
 ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -ar 8000 file.wav
```

> Acoustic models: If I don't upsample/downsample the stream, how can I find an acoustic model supporting 11025 kHz. If I do, what is the best model for digits?

en-us-8khz is available in downloads, you need to create a digits grammar as in [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm) and then use it in the following way

```
 pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav -jsgf digits.gram -hmm en-us-8khz -samprate 8000
```

> Recognition mode: I found there are two modes for transcribing - Key spotting and Recognition. Whichmode would be better taking into account I have only digits (and some noise)

Recognition mode

Comment: Thank you, Nokilay. My lucky combination is:

`pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav -jsgf digits.gram -hmm voxforge_model -samprate 8000 -remove_dc yes -remove_noise no -vad_threshold 3.4 -vad_prespeech 19 -vad_postspeech 37 -silprob 2.5`

CMU Sphinx FAQ says:
_Zero silence regions in audio files decoded from mp3 break the decoder. You can use dither to introduce small random noise to solve this problem._ 

Do you mean it can affect the result?

Comment: No, voxforge model must be much less accurate. Your additional arguments are also wrong, you should not disable the noise removal. To analyze bad accuracy you need to provide few test samples. I suggest you to discuss this issue on cmusphinx forum, it does not really fit stackoverflow format.

Comment: For those who is interested in, the continuation is here:
https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/654ed756/